# C# XNA: How to get asteroid bouncing off all sides of the screen

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to make an asteroids game and have managed to get the asteroid to move in a straight line from one side to the screen to the other however, it runs in an infinite straight line instead of bouncing off all the sides of the screen like i want it to.

Code that moves the asteroid:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        position.X = position.X + speed;
        position.Y = position.Y + speed;

        if (position.X <= 0)
        {
            position.X = 0;
            speed = random.Next(-3,3);
        }
        // Right Boundary
        if (position.X >= 1280 - texture.Width)
        {
            position.X = 1280 - texture.Width;
            speed = random.Next(-3,3);
        }
        // Top Boundary
        if (position.Y <= 0)
        {
            position.Y = 0;
            speed = random.Next(-3,3);
        }
        //Bottom Boundary
        if (position.Y >= 1024 - texture.Height)
        {
            position.Y = 1024 - texture.Height;
            speed = random.Next(-3,3);
        }
    }
```

How would I go about amending this code so that it stops moving in a straight line and bounces off all the sides of the screen. 
(position and speed are declared within a superclass and the value of speed is declared within the asteroids class constructor)
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet, im going to try my best to understand your question.
from my understanding what happens to you is that the astroids go straight up and down instead of bouncing all around the screen?

I would suggest you to use matrices, and to create a rotation like that. you can read more about it here treating the astroid like a rocket, and implamenting in your own code:

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Angle_to_Direction.php

Answer (score 0):

first create your asteroids at random places, and add them radnom velocity.vector2. so on your update function you update like this:

```
position += velocity
```

then use this function to reverse velocity if bounce.

```
 private void CheckCollision()
 {
     if (position.X < 0){
         position.X = 0;
        velocity.X *= -1;
     }
     if (position.X + texture.Width > screenBounds.Width){
        position.X = screenBounds.Width - texture.Width;
        velocity.X *= -1;
     }
     if (position.Y < 0){
         position.Y = 0;
         velocity.Y *= -1;
     }
 }
```